# Swagger - can't reference JSON file

Tags: json, api, swagger, ref, platform

I'm using Swagger via annotations (API Platform) and I'm trying to reference to JSON file located in the same directory as my entity.

What I have:

Entity.php

```
"swagger_context" = {
    "responses"={
         "200"={
             "schema"={
                  "$ref"="foo.json"
             }
```

foo.json

```
{
    "foo":"bar"
}
```

JSON file is not read - schema is not displayed in API documentation. What's the issue?